# `pmatrix` line break

Tags: line-breaking, matrices

I wrote a matrix using the `pmatrix` environment.
The content is very long and LaTeX produces an output of the kind (the "a" line extending beyond `\textwidth`):

```
( aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa )
( bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb               )
( cccccccccccccccccc                    )
```

I would like to get:

```
( aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa )
(           + aaa aaa aaa ) [aligned right]
( bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb )
( cccccccccccccccccc      )
```

Can someone please help me?
Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}
    aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa \\
    bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb\\
    cccccccccccccccccc
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I doubt if *any* matrix environment is adequate for your expression, which appears to have 9 entries in the first row, 8 in the second, and only 1 in the third. (Usually, matrices are rectangular arrays with an equal number of entries in each row.)

Answer (score 6):

The only problem with simply adding an extra line break is the alignment, which you can fix by adding a `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}
    aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa \\
   \hfill + aaa aaa aaa \\
    bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb\\
    cccccccccccccccccc
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd add `{}` in front of `+` in order to get correct spacing.